# Django: Form check if field has no error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to add the `has-success` if a field has no error.

What I tried:

```
<div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% elif not field.errors} has-success{% endif %}">
```

But it is not working. If the field has errors the `has-error` is added (this part works).

BUT `not field.errors` is also true when the form has not been submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the form has errors.

```
<div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% elif form.is_bound %} has-success{% endif %}">
```

This supposes the form variable in your template context is named `form`.

Comment: **Works!** But why did you remove the previous solution? It was working too (I was wrong).

Comment: @mkay well checking for `not field.errors` is superfluous because of the previous `if` condition and using [is_bound](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_bound) is more explicit than checking for errors, but indeed in term of result, they are equivalent.

Comment: Ok. Merci beaucoup monsieur :)